# Carrierwave integration with DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave, digital-ocean

I am working on `Rails` application that is deployed on `DigitalOcean` server and integerated `Carrierwave` gem to store images. I want to use `DigitalOcean` [storage](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/object-storage/) space to store and access images from my `Rails` application.

But I am unable to find that how can I integerate with `Carrierwave` gem to use in my Application. I have created a separate storage on `DigitalOcean` which they provided on 2 Months Trial. But I am unable to find `Apis` to use it with `CArrierwave`.

Please help me how can I integerate it with `Carrierwave` to use in my `Rails` Application?

Answer (score 3):

Check this answer on the `fog` board: https://github.com/fog/fog-digitalocean/issues/20#issuecomment-332009742

In short, using `gem fog-aws` and making these modifications:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => [YOUR_ACCESS_KEY],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => [YOUR_SECRET_KEY],
    :region                 => 'nyc3',
    :endpoint               => 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'your-space-name'
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

in `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb` should do the trick.

Comment: I have used the same configurations. How can I fetch any object/image or store any object/image on DO server? I haven't found any API in rails.

Comment: you have posted question for how to setup carrier-wave with digital ocean which I have already give an answer. Now fetching data/image from digital ocean is another question so open a new question for it. And please mark the answer as correct

Comment: Wrote a little tutorial on it here if you are interested: https://medium.com/@erickhoury/uploading-images-from-rails-to-digitalocean-spaces-with-previewing-8e10f427a02b

Answer (score 0):

For storing images on the digital ocean you need to use Fog gem with carrier wave. Refer this [link](https://github.com/fog/fog-digitalocean)

Comment: How can I store and retrieve any image on space storage using Carrierwave on DO server?